# Why isn't my sprite moving when a key is pressed?

Tags: python, pygame

I don't know why but when I press the up key, there is no error but nothing happens to my sprite. I've tried looking on the pygame docs but whatever I do, nothing works.

```
def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.char = os.path.join(player_folder, "p_stand.png")
    self.walkcount = 0
    self.jumping = False
    self.jumpCount = 0
    self.image = pygame.image.load(self.char).convert()
    self.image.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.right = 0
    self.rect.bottom = int(height - 70)

def update(self):
    self.keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if self.keys[pygame.K_UP] and self.jumping == False:
        self.jumping = True

    if self.jumping:
        if self.jumpCount <= 5:
            self.rect.move(0, 1)
            self.jumpCount += 1
        elif self.jumpCount > 5 and self.jumpCount < 10:
            self.rect.move(0, -1)
            self.jumpCount += 1
        else:
            self.jumpCount = 0
            self.jumping = False
```

Comment: What is `self.rect` and what does its `move` method do? Please show us a [mcve].

Comment: sorry, ill add the init function to it

Comment: Do you have an event loop? The states which are returned by `pygame.key.get_pressed()` are updated when the events are handled.

Comment: yes, thats in my main file

Comment: the functions which make the sprite move left and right that i havent put here work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pygame.Rect.move`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move) does not change the position attributes of the object instance. The method creates a new [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) with the new location and returns it.
You have to assign the return value to the attribute. e.g.:

<s>`self.rect.move(0, -1)`</s>

```py
self.rect = self.rect.move(0, -1)
```

In pygame the direction of the y axis is down. If you want to jump up, then you have to `move(0, -1)`:

```py
def update(self):
    self.keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if self.keys[pygame.K_UP] and self.jumping == False:
        self.jumping = True

    if self.jumping:
        if self.jumpCount <= 5:
            self.rect = self.rect.move(0, -1)
            self.jumpCount += 1
        elif self.jumpCount > 5 and self.jumpCount < 10:
            self.rect = self.rect.move(0, 1)
            self.jumpCount += 1
        else:
            self.jumpCount = 0
            self.jumping = False
```